# Multiple POST request in a single form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following form, which contains just an email input.

```
<form action="model.php" name="f1mail" method="POST" id="form45">
    <input id="field0" type="email" name="email" class="field" required>
    <input type="submit" class="start submit-button" value="Next">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted I need to do two things with this client information.
First I need to send this email to a database hosted in another server. Secondly I need to call a php file in the same server.
To do so, I call the php file in the action of the form and then did this AJAX code to do the request to the external url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Process the form
    $('#form45').submit(function(event) {
        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url         : 'https://my_url?&callback=',
            data        : 'email=' + email,
            type        : 'POST',
            dataType    : 'jsonp',
            success     : function(resp) {
                alert(resp);
            },
            error       : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work. Anyone knows how two submit the same information of a form to two different URL's at the same time? I don't know if there is other way, It hasn't to be AJAX, maybe with Python and Flask or other language is easier to achieve. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: You could make a normal request to your own server and make a cURL request from there to the external url.

Comment: Make multiple ajax request?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? Does the external server support CORS? If not, you would more than likely have to proxy the call from a URL on your own server..

Comment: @Steve yes it does, it's the OracleEloqua page. It supports CORS. Shall I make both requests in the PHP file?

Comment: If it's not the same url, you will get a 'Same origin policy' error. I would send it to your own server, and the i would make a cURL request, like @jeroen wrote.

Comment: @DaBra ok thanks! I'll try it now

Comment: @DaBra I would suggest he check the browser console for any errors first, it may well be sending the wrong data, wrong url etc. The description of "But this doesn't work" isn't very helpful in regards to errors being returned etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it. For anyone with the same issue, here's my solution of what I did.

As some people told me in the comments, I used the cURL library of PHP to make a POST request and then do all other stuff I need. Let me explain...

Instead of calling two different URL's I just called the one in my own server, the model.php page you can see in the action of the form. This page had some stuff to do with the email information. But before all this stuff begun, I put this code in order to do a POST request to the external URL and then the code followed with the previous need.

```
<?php
    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();
    // Set up the request for external_url
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://external_url',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'sample',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'email'          => $email,
            // More vars if needed
            ...
        )
    ));
    // Send the request and check errors
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$resp){
        die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
    }
    // Clear up resources
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```